# Claw Free Graphs

Tags: algorithm, graph

I have been reading this  [wiki article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Claw-free_graph) on how to find if the graph is claw-free or not but I cannot understand some part of it.

Algorithm says(Under the recognition title) "...one can test whether a graph is claw-free by checking for each vertex of the graph, that the complement graph of its neighbors does not contain a triangle".

Now we can test whether a graph(represented in adjacency matrix) contains a triangle or not 
by simply calculating G*G*G and if its trace(sum of all main diagonal elements) is zero no triangle exits.

What is meant by "for each vertex of the graph, that the complement graph of its neighbors"?

Does it means that I should take Complement of the graph for every vertex and check for triangle or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For each vertex, you take the subgraph induced by that vertex and it's neighbours. Then, you take the complement of each of these subgraphs and check each one for triangles independently.